# relaunch an Activity after notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

I Have an Activity A, it launch Activity B, and B launch a Service S.
at this point if i am in B and touch HOME BUTTON and then start again the app shows me Activity B. Thats OK.
The problem is when Service S launch a Notification, if I open the notification, and then press BACK BUTTON or use finish(), if I start app again shows me Activity A, and it not ok, i want to see Activity B.
Another solucion that im trying to find is that notificacion sends me directly to Activity B after press it.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Once an application starts, by default it will load your **Main Activity** which in that case is **Activity A** (Back button and `finish()` destroy the activity), by pressing the **Home** button, the application is not closed, it just goes to the background, so when you started it again, it just came to the front again, and **Activity B** is still running.

What you need to do is modify your Notification to start **Activity B** on click. This is what you need to do:

1. Create your notification builder.
2. Create a PendingIntent that has an intent to the Activity you would like to start.
3. Assign the PendingIntent to the notification builder.
4. build and send the notification.

Call this method on the notification Builder and pass it the PendingIntent:
`builder.setContentIntent(onClickPendingIntent);`

Also you might want to establish the normal workflow of your application (if you press back in activity B it should take you to A, not outside the application which will happen if you try), to achieve that you need to create a **`TaskStackBuilder`**. Take a look at this documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html